# Zero-out entire char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char

I am trying to zero-out an entire `char` pointer. If I perform the statement:

`memset(myCharPointer, 0, sizeof(myCharPointer));`

it only zeros-out the first 4 bytes because that is the size of a `char` pointer on my system.

So how can I ensure that the data is completely set to 0? Setting it to `NULL` does not wipe out the entire `char` pointer.

Comment: dont you have the length of your charpointer ? Is this a NUL-Terminated CSTring? if so, you can use strlen.

Comment: You should be the one who knows how much data there is to zero-out, no?

Comment: You can't do this unless you know the length of the char pointer (which you should know since you are the one who allocated it).

Comment: Since this question is tagged C++, I'm a bit surprised that none of the answers or comments suggested using `std::fill()` or `std::fill_n()` with the appropriate end iterator or length parameter, respectively - at least as a matter of style/convention.  `memset()` is of course valid in this case, too.

Comment: In case you are going to do this right after a memory allocation, remember calloc does memory allocation and zero initialization all in one: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/

Comment: @Void: I don't think he really meant C++, as he was using memset in the question.  Re-tagging...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sizeof(myCharPointer)` is going to give you a `sizeof(char*)`, which is the size of a *pointer*, which is usually four bytes.  A sizeof(char) is going to give you 1 byte.

To do the memset you need to know how long your data is.  e.g.,

`memset(myCharPointer, 0, myCharPointerLen)`;

Comment: Why not do something simpler: `myCharPointer = 0`?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, he wants to put zeros into the data *pointed to* by myCharPointer.  He doesn't want to NULL-out the pointer itself.

Answer (score 5):

if you know the length of the char array you are pointing to you can do this:

```
memset(myCharPointer, 0, sizeof(*myCharPointer) * length);
```

Also, I believe you should use the `sizeof` the pointer contents instead of that of the pointer itself.

Comment: taking back the acceptance since I found out that the above statement crashes my application but the new accepted answer does not

Comment: you should be memsetting the length.  Don't multiply by the size of.  print out the sizeof a char and see what it is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the size of myCharPointer in some variable or constant when creating it. Then you pass that to the memset function.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use strlen(myCharPointer); which will return the size up to the NULL termination.
you could even embed it right in the memset,

```
memset(myCharPointer, 0, strlen(myCharPointer));
```

or simply

```
ULONG size = strlen(myCharPointer);
memset(myCharPointer, 0, size);
```

The Previous solutons ARE one way, storing the size in a variable, but your char* is NULL terminated ie. (with bytes represented by char's)

> A, K, J, P, 2, Q, M, NULL

strlen will count from your char* address until the NULL, *voila*

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it how many bytes to zero out, so sizeof(myCharPointer)*<length to zero>.

Comment: -1 that will give an incorrect answer as `sizeof(myCharPointer)` is 4 (or 8, whatever the pointer size is) not 1. `sizeof(*myCharPointer)` or just `sizeof(char)` would be *more correct* (though not necessarily the best).

Comment: Interesting.  Been a LONG while since I've had to use memset, thanks for the clarification.